# Apache Nutch title parsing issue for Language specific websites

Tags: parsing, nutch, apache-tika, nutch2

I have configured apache Nutch 2.3.1 with Hadoop 2.7.5 and Hbase 0.98. I have to crawl some Urdu websites. I am using its default parsers i.e., html, tika. Some documents have title in Urdu that are ok but some documents have title in Urdu and their heading 1 i.e., h1 have the original title e.g. [bbc-page](https://www.bbc.com/urdu/india/story/2006/02/printable/060214_mumbaievent_video_sq.shtml). Similarly, there are some cases where meta tags have relvement title. Is there any builtin option (parser) that can handle this option so that it should select h1 for title if available.

Or if I have to do it, what are possible ways for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nutch will use the `title` tag if present found in the DOM tree (https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/bb2a7adddbc5c780151bb9957d68af52be7339ca/src/plugin/parse-tika/src/java/org/apache/nutch/parse/tika/DOMContentUtils.java#L251) for this you would need to write a custom logic in a parser plugin. But the real question would be how would you identify the "bad" `title` tag? Would be some specific content (like the URL).

In any case, you'll need to write your own plugin either in the parser or in an indexing plugin (like taking a field and copying it over to the title field in certain conditions).

Comment: that's brother, actually there are some titles in some crawled documents that are totally in non-Urdu language, these are bad titles for our case.

Comment: In this case, you could write your own plugin that identifies the language of the title and if it's different than the language of the document (assuming that the language is set/identified correctly for your webpages) will copy the text from the `h1` tag. Unfortunately there is no built-in way of doing this.